Azure: there is no package called ‘dynlm’
Context:
I have uploaded the zip file of the proper package version related to the R version inside the src dir of the compute instance.
I have the following code:
# R version: 3.5.1
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.

# Please note that functions dependant on X11 library
# such as "View" are not supported because X11 library
# is not pre-installed.

# The entry point function MUST have two input arguments.
# If the input port is not connected, the corresponding
# dataframe argument will be null.
#   Param<dataframe1>: a R DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a R DataFrame
azureml_main <- function(dataframe1, dataframe2)
  {
  print("script run.")
  install.packages("src/dynlm.zip", lib = ".",  repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)
  print("Install phase passed.")
  library(dynlm)
  print("library phase passed.")
  require(zoo)
  require(stats)
    
  # Specify which Packages are required to run script. The dynlm package needs to be zipped up with this script to work in Azure ML.
  require(data.table)
  
  return(list(dataset1=dataframe1, dataset2=dataframe2))
}

I tried different solutions but I still get the error there is no package called ‘dynlm’ even though I think I clearly specify the installation. What can I do?
Side details:  before I did other tries, I did some downgrades

pip:

azureml-core==1.54.0
cryptography<41



let me know if you need more context. I considered dockerizing the code

Where do you see the error? In the Azure ML pipeline or somewhere else?

in the log of the R script inside the pipeline

before install.packages("src/dynlm.zip"
add some more prints …
cat("\n does src exist? ",dir.exists("src"),"\n")
print("src contents")
print(list.files("src"))
cat("\n does src/dynlm.zip exist? ",file.exists(src/dynlm.zip),"\n")

how you uploaded the zip file into compute instance?

via notebook, where I uploaded the file after creating the directory src

workaround:
install.packages("r-cran-dynlm", repos = "https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r-cran-dynlm", dependencies=TRUE)


Ok. I thought you wanted to install only with zip package.

That is because the installation is not successful. You need to check whether the src file present or not.  But whatever you uploaded in compute instance it will not be shared while running the pipeline.
So, possible way is to provide the zip file dataset in port 3 which accepts zip file and extracts it in the folder Script Bundle.
Next, register the dataset with the downloaded zip file.
Go to Data  and click on create.

Give a name and select dataset types as file.

then click on From Local Files and upload the package zip file you have.
Now in pipeline add the data created to 3rd port like shown below.

Next use below r script to install it.
print(list.files('./Script Bundle'))
install.packages("./Script Bundle/dynlm", repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)

Since, it is already extracted to Script Bundle give the package path to folder dynlm.
Output:

Also make sure you have all dependencies while loading.

Thanks we solved before reading this, passing through CRAN, and surprisingly it worked

Please add it in answer so that it helps the community to find better solution. Meanwhile check the provided approach once.

Newbie question: after the run, the package2 box shall become green?
Also, can you please expand this: "Also make sure you have all dependencies while loading."? Do you mean I need to add the .zips of all the dependecies? I shake thinking about that.

I added the car dependency, but when running print(list.files('./Script Bundle')), it just sees dynlm

What are you trying to do? You already given solution, installing viaw repos.
